# meteor iron-router onStop get the next url

Tags: meteor, iron-router

when the user routes away from my controller, I want to where the user is been redirected, just before he is redirected

the "onStop" hook lets me catch the right place but I can not get the next url

this is my router function

```
Router.route('page', {
    name:"page",
    onStop: function(){
      //runs once when the controller is stopped, like just before a user routes away.

     //WHAT IS THE NEXT PATH????????
    }
});
```

Comment: Wat? You want to know where the user is going before going there?

Comment: yes. the user clicked on an ahref or did Rounter.go somewhere. in that moment the current rout fires "onStop". I want to know where the user is going

Comment: Did you try `Router.current().route.getName()` ?

Comment: yes, it gives me the current rout. in this point the rout did not change yet. the onStop happens right before the user is navigated away

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a onBeforeAction? like:

```
Router.route('page', {
name:"page",
onBeforeAction: function(){
    var nextRoute = Router.current().route.getName();
}
```

});

```
Router.current().route.getName();  //will be the next route within onBeforeAction
```